# Passing values from views to controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have templated my Angular app with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), so my app directory structure is nice and neat and will give you an idea of how my project is constructed. I have 2 routes in my app, one is called 'main' and the other 'sub'.

When I'm in my 'main' view, I have a link that then forwards the user to the 'sub' view. How can I pass a simple value to the 'sub' controller through the link from my 'main' view?

i.e. my link is just a standard html link:

```
<a href="/#/sub">Go to sub</a>
```

When you hit that the sub.js controller can add some data to $scope for the sub view and so on. I want to access the value in the 'sub' controller that was passed from the 'main' view... Hope that makes sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you basically want to communicate between two controllers.
The first instinct might be to create a parent scope and bind data to it, but there is a better way, a service.

You bind data to this service and it can act as the messenger between your controllers, like so:

```
angular.module('app', [])

  .factory('Data', dataService)

  .controller('firstController', firstController)
  .controller('secondController', secondController);

function dataService() {
  return { message: "I'm data from a service" };
}

function firstController($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;
}

function secondController($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;
}
```

And markup:

```
<h2>First controller</h2>
<div ng-controller="firstController">
  <input type="text" ng-model=data.message  />
  {{ data.message }}
</div> 

<h2>Second controller</h2>
<div ng-controller="secondController">
  <input type="text" ng-model=data.message  />
  {{ data.message }}                        
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/xuxevo/1/)
[Explained very good at egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

bind the variable `dataToFoward` which is a $scope variable in mainCtrl

```
<a ng-href="#/sub/{{dataToFoward}}">Go to sub</a>
```

in routes,

```
when("/sub/:sampleData", {templateUrl: "pathToTemplate" }).
```

in Sub Controller,

```
app.controller('subCtrl', function($routeParams,$scope) {
    $scope.fromMain = $routeParams.sampleData;
});
```

Comment: In the link, do I HAVE to use 'ng-href' or is a normal 'href' also fine?

Comment: its good to use `ng-href` because **may be** `$scope.dataToFoward` variable is not set in the controller when you clicking the link.

Comment: if `$scope.dataToFoward` not set when you clicking the link `href="#/sub/{{dataToFoward}}"` will result in a `404` error, but `ng-href="#/sub/{{dataToFoward}}"` is acting as link only after`dataToFoward` is set , it will not clickable before the `dataToFoward` is set.